# Trying to get property of non-object when trying to select a value from the result

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with the function. I make a request to select from the database, the selection is normal and there is a second code that should take the value of the `price` column from the result, but the problem is that I get an error as a result: `Trying to get property of non-object`.

My code:

```
$betitem = \DB::table('items')->where('status', 0)->where('price', '>=', 10)->orderByRaw('RAND()')->take(1)->get();
$green_tickets = $betitem->price;
```

If write `var_dump($betitem[0]); exit;` i received:

```
object(stdClass)#584 (13) { ["id"]=> int(548) ["assetid"]=> string(11) "18235855849" ["market_hash_name"]=> string(15) "Staff of Gun-Yu" ["classid"]=> string(231) "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KW1Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXK9QlSPcU_phVWSVXvTO2j0IDeXFN_IB1ovbOrLDhp3v7HYylD4OOhkYGbmPm7PrTfnW5I1854hO7-_IH4h0agqh8DJDyiZNnLbAE8M13Q-Ae4wrq7g5Pq7cufnCRm7nZ3tCyPlhSyhx1IabZrjPKaQVqAR_se2_6rU3g" ["price"]=> float(26.4) ["steamid"]=> string(1) "1" ["type"]=> string(4) "card" ["bot"]=> string(1) "1" ["status"]=> int(0) ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2020-02-27 01:47:12" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2020-03-14 17:41:25" ["is_withdraw"]=> int(0) ["is_raffling"]=> int(0) }
```

How i understand the problem arises because the result is received in an array. But then how to fix this error and get the result from the `price` column?

Comment: Didn't you answer your own question in the code? You wrote `$betitem->price`, but the in the dump `$betitem[0]`, meaning you know it's an array.

Comment: add ```toArray()``` after ```get()``` in items query

Comment: @El_Vanja `$betitem[0]` it's example, that which shows an array (as I understand it)

Comment: @Zain received `Fatal error: Call to a member function toArray() on array`, if change to `$green_tickets = $betitem->price->toArray();`, i received error from question `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: Ok, so the object with the properties you need is *the first element of the result array*. How do you access the first element of an array? Hint: you did it in the `var_dump`.

Comment: if i understand you, access to the first elements, it's `$betitem`

Comment: I think you should use  ([]) instead of object access (->). , as you said you get array in result , so you can try $betitem['price']

Comment: now i received `Undefined index: price`, but `price` column exist at database and filled

Comment: first, you have to see the array structure by dump or dd() query result then perform the action accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$betitem` has an object inside an array, you can do

```
$green_tickets = $betitem[0]->price;
```

Or you can use the [`first()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#retrieving-results) method to get the first row matching your conditions.

```
$betitem = \DB::table('items')->where('status', 0)->where('price', '>=', 10)->orderByRaw('RAND()')->take(1)->first();

$green_tickets = $betitem->price;
```

Also, I can see an extra `\` before `DB`. You can add `use DB;` before declaration of your class and it should run just fine. Make sure this `DB` alias exists in your `config/ app.php`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$betitem  = items::where('status',0)->andWhere('price', '>=', 10)->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->take(1)->get(); 
$green_tickets = $betitem->price;
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case use first() instead of take(1)->get()

```
$betitem = \DB::table('items')->where('status', 0)->where('price', '>=', 10)->orderByRaw('RAND()')->first();
$green_tickets = $betitem->price;
```